# AWS EC2 Unaccountable Costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have the following distributed JavaEE set up which I let run for exactly one day (24 hours) to check if I can reconstruct the costs manually. In order to generate some workload I used an Load Test Driver which runs on my local machine and emulates user requests to the system. I'm using the region EU (Frankfurt) and all my instances are in the same Availability Zone.

[image: AWS Setup]

Now when I take a look at the Amazon Cost Reporter the following costs are reported. Here are the costs grouped by Instance Type:
[image: Instance Costs]

And here are the costs grouped by API Operation:
[image: API Costs]

The instance `m4.xlarge` costs $`0.285` per Hour which means `3 x 24 x 0.285 = 20.52`. That's exactly the same what the Amazon Cost Reporter says.

Now I have costs for RunInstances which is `22.80` and when I subtract the costs for the three instances I get `22.80 - 20.52 = 2.28`.

The next thing I would to is to subtract the costs for the EBS Volumes which is $`0.119` per GB-month of provisioned storage. So in my case I have `32GB * 0.119 = 3.808 per Month`. In order to get the costs per day I divide it through 30.5 and get `3.808 / 30.5 = 0.125`.

Now when I subtract the costs for the EBS Volumes from the remaining instance costs I get `2.28 - 0.125 = 2.155`. But what now where do this remaining `2`$ come from? Do I have some mistakes in my calculation or are there other costs I don't consider so far?

Any help or pointers would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You are using elastic IP address the data transfer cost for Elastic IP address is $ 0.01/GB IN and $ 0.01/GB OUT. So please consider that too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But aren't those costs already considered in the second diagram for PublicIP-In and PublicIP-Out?

Comment: Yes but you are not using Public IP you are using elastic Public IP address. Public IP address data transfer is free Check this Cost Page http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/#Elastic_IP_Addresses

Comment: Hmm but still it's too much I have only 2GB of data going in and out... This would only make `0.04`$ and I still have more than `2`$ remaining...

Comment: Ho Do you know it is 2 GB data in and out?

Comment: I monitored the data transfer between my Load Test Driver and the VM1. I installed a network monitoring tool on both machines.

Comment: What is the type of EBS volume you are using General Purpose or some thing different?

Comment: I'm using the Amazon EBS General Purpose SSD (gp2) volumes.